# Problem with Quotes while using variables with "&" and "%"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping, parameter-passing

I've been sitting here for 3 days now trying to solve the following problem.
I need a call function that I can pass a url as a parameter to. However, this URL has an `&`, which no longer works as soon as I pass the variable as a call parameter.
I can't set `/&` in the Url, because its a dynamic Url.

Every url begins with `https://` and ends with `&dl=1`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "url=!array[2]!"

call :do_download
   
:do_download 
    powershell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
       Invoke-WebRequest '%url%' -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.zip'"
```

But if i try in all versions of quotes, doublequotes, with trimm or other tricks, it dont work :´(
I have rly no idea yet. But i need the Url as call-param.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "url=!array[2]!"

call :do_download "%url%"

:do_download 
    powershell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
       Invoke-WebRequest '%1' -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.zip'"
```

If you try it self:
you can save a `packs.txt` with:

```
Testlink
https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/76ffff3d76ea4e9ab15e/files/?p=%2FTest.txt&dl=1
```

The link is to download a `.txt` file with 200 words from lorem ipsum.
and here is the complete code, that will work at this moment, but without call-param. you can set the paths whatever you want, it's only for example.
This code runs by itself; the `!` are used because later it will be inside an `if`, but that code is independent of this one.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :readtest
pause
call :do_download
pause

:readtest
    set count=0
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\packs.txt") do (
        set /a count+=1
        set url[!count!]=%%A
    )
    set "pack_sd=!url[2]!"
    goto :eof

:do_download 
powershell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest '%pack_sd%' -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\test.txt'"
goto :eof
```

If i try the answer with use: :"=

```
call :do_download "%pack_sd%"
    
:do_download 
    echo TT %1 TT
    set "url=%1"
    set test=%url:"=%
    echo "TT %test% TT"
```

first echo:

```
TT "https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/76ffff3d76ea4e9ab15e/files/?p=FTest.txt&dl=1" TT
```

second echo:

```
error: command "dl" is wrong or unknown...
"TT "= TT"
```

If i try the answer with %~1

```
call :do_download "%pack_sd%"

:do_download 
    echo TT %1 TT
    set url=%~1
    echo "TT %url% TT%
```

first echo:

```
TT "https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/76ffff3d76ea4e9ab15e/files/?p=FTest.txt&dl=1" TT
```

second echo:

```
error: command "dl" is wrong or unknown...
"TT https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/76ffff3d76ea4e9ab15e/files/?p=FTest.txt TT"
```

if i use the answer with: '%1:"=' inside powershell command:

```
call :do_download "%pack_sd%"

:do_download 
        powershell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest '%1:"=' -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\test.txt'"
    goto :eof 

error: "The string has no terminator: '."
```

Comment: @mklement0, I'm sure you meant `'%~1'`…

Comment: There must be something that prevents execution from continuing after the `call` command and before the label `:do_download`…

Comment: i tried %~1 but it dont work.
and if i use doublequotes around url the powershell commant dont work, cause the double quotes close the command.

Comment: the problem is, that everytime if i delete the quotes: &dl=1 is interpreted as command.
but the wierd thing is, if i set the url without quotes and use the variable directly, it works. but if i use the variable as call-param, it wont work. not with quotes, not with doublequotes, not without quotes...

Comment: Well you could use `'%~1'`, or I suppose `\"%~1\"`. The key here is that `~` expands the argument/parameter variable removing the enclosing double-quotes. In the latter example the ```\``` character escapes the nested quote from the cmd parser. For information about substitution of batch parameters, open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: i try it, but same solution with %~1 and \"%~1\". the error is everytime "the string has no closing quote and "dl" ist written wrong or unknown :(

Comment: In order for us to assist further we need a [mcve]. That means specifically that we need the exact content of `%array[2]%"` and preferably all of the code which defines it! It would also help if you can specifically verify that your end user has write access to `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and whether you're trying to run this script elevated, or as a standard user.

Comment: It might help if you simply wrote the entire thing in powershell

Comment: I think so yes, but i get an error with "The string has no terminator: '."
and i can use :"=% before the powershell or in powershell... both times the same solution. i think before the double quotes can delete, the batch script get the error.

Answer (score 3):

---

The problem boils down to this:

- The requirement to support not just `&` but also `%` characters in your URLs significantly complicates the solution, unfortunately, because `cmd.exe` (inappropriately) subjects a parameter's verbatim value passed to a subroutine via `call` to string interpolation, which necessitates *doubling* the `%` in the value in order to preserve them.

  - Thus, a URL read from a file with `for /f` must have its `%` *programmatically doubled* before passing it as a parameter to `call :do_download`, which is a nontrivial undertaking - see the code below and the source-code comments.
  - Note that *additional* effort would be required if your URL also contained `!` characters.
- In your `:do_download` subroutine, use `set "url=%~1"`. This stores the *unquoted* value of `%1` (the first parameter) in variable `%url%`

  - Do *not* use `set "url=%1"` or `set url=%~1`, both of which predictably *break* with a `%1` value that has embedded surrounding double quotes and contains `&`.
  - Do *not* use `%1:"=`, which doesn't do what you think it does. `%1` is a *parameter*, whereas the string-substitution syntax you're trying to use only works with *variables* (e.g., `%url:"=%`)
- Then you can use `%url%` *as-is* inside the `"..."` string that forms the `powershell -c` argument - or you could just use `%~1` directly.

  - With the intermediate `%url%` variable, however, you could alternatively take advantage of the fact that all `cmd.exe` variables (but not *parameters* such as `%1`) are also *environment* variables, which therefore allows PowerShell to access the URL via an *environment-variable reference* instead of embedding it directly in the command string (the equivalent of cmd.exe's `%url%` is `$env:url` in PowerShell). That is, you could replace the `powershell` call below with the following - note how enclosing `'...'` quoting as part of the PowerShell command must then *not* be used:

    - `powershell -c "Write-Output $env:url"`

Here's a minimal example that shows that a URL containing both `&` and `%` characters is correctly passed through to PowerShell; everything else in your code is incidental (use of `for /f`, specifics of the PowerShell command):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Use a sample URL that contains both & and % characters.
:: Note: The % must be DOUBLED here in order to escape it.
::       The resulting string will only have ONE %, as desired and will therefore
::       literally be the following, as it would be read from a file with `for /f`: 
::          http://example.org?p=%2FTest.txt&dl=1
set "url=http://example.org?p=%%2FTest.txt&dl=1"

:: Unfortunately, using `call` requires escaping of % even in variable values, 
:: as the embedded single % are then again subject to variable expansion
:: (even though they shouldn't be).
:: Doubling % *programmatically* is non-trivial and requires a helper variable
:: as well as mixing up-front and delayed expansion.
:: The following string substitution effectively doubles the embedded % chars.
:: so that the :do_download subroutine again sees them as verbatim single ones.

set "pct=%%"
call :do_download "!url:%pct%=%%%%!"

goto :eof

:do_download
  set "url=%~1"
  powershell -c "Write-Output '%url%'"
goto :eof
```

The above prints verbatim `http://example.org?p=%2FTest.txt&dl=1`, proving that the URL was correctly passed through to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "url=!array[2]!"

call :do_download
   
:do_download 
    powershell -c "$Url=$Env:url; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
       Invoke-WebRequest $Url -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.zip'"
```

You have Delayed Explansion enabled, so you should be able to just past the variable's name and expand it later.

Does this also work?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "url=!array[2]!"

call :do_download url
GOTO :EOF

:do_download 
    powershell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
       Invoke-WebRequest $Env:!%~1! -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.zip'"
```

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if the packs.txt file contains only URLs or other content.  I placed 5 copies of the sync.luckycloud.de URL, the one mentioned in the question, in a mock packs.txt file and was able to get this code to work.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
GOTO :Start

:ReadTest
    SET Count=0
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ EOL=` TOKENS=* DELIMS=`" %%U IN ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\packs.txt") DO (
        SET /A Count+=1
        SET url[!count!]=%%U
    )
    SET "pack_sd=!url[2]!"
GOTO :EOF

:Do_Download
    PowerShell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest $Env:pack_sd -OutFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\test.txt'"
GOTO :EOF

:Start
    CALL :ReadTest
    CALL :Do_Download
GOTO :EOF
```

**NOTE:** I believe the characters below are not allowed as part of a URL.  The FOR command first looks for DELIMS, but there should never be a back tick in the URL, so DELIMS should never be found.  But if one is found, it is grabbed by DELIMS before EOL, this make EOL disabled.  The default for EOL is a semicolon, which appears to be a valid character in URLs.  So it is important to disable EOL, or give it a value that will never be in a URL.

```
"%\^`{|}<>
```

**Final Generic Version:**

ReadFile: Takes name of array for saving URLs and the path of a file containing URLs.  Reads file, storing URLs in array.

Do_Downloads: Takes name of array of URLs and the path where files will be saved. URLs from array are downloaded and saved to files with name WebFile{N}.txt, where {N} is the line number the URL came from in the file containing URLs.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
GOTO :Start

:ReadFile
    SET Count=0
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ EOL=` TOKENS=* DELIMS=`" %%U IN ("%~2") DO (
        SET /A Count+=1
        SET %~1[!Count!]=%%U
    )
GOTO :EOF

:Do_Downloads
    FOR /L %%I IN (1, 1, %Count%) DO (
        SET Url=!%~1[%%I]!
        PowerShell -c "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest $Env:Url -OutFile '%~2\WebFile%%I.txt'"
    )
GOTO :EOF

:Start
    CALL :ReadFile Urls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\packs.txt"
    CALL :Do_Downloads Urls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Yes, this will work :) but how can i use $Url=$Env:url with %1 from the call-function? :)

Comment: @Datasmuggler, I've added another section of code, but I'm not actually testing this code, just writing what has worked in code I've been using.  This time, instead of saving the environmental variable url in a PS variable first, I'm trying to use it directly.  If this doesn't work, then we may go back and to storing in a variable first.  Either way, passing the name of the variable in BATCH, instead of the content, should work.

Comment: thanks :) it will be work.... not :(
the powershell get the correct url now, but it execute with error, because the control character & is reserved and can only use in doublequotes. but if i use doublequotes, there are not in the output.
grrrrrr... i begin to realy hate batch :D
If i use the url directly, all will be fine. no troubleshooting with &...

Comment: If i use $Url=$Env:!%1!;  at the beginning of powershell command i get an error, because th doubleslash is es problem. And the second error ist the same with &

Comment: Does this fail?  Invoke-WebRequest "$($Env:!%~1!)"

Comment: Sorry, just realized you are in double quotes.  That last idea won't work.

Comment: Hmm, what if you double double quote? Invoke-WebRequest ""$($Env:!%~1!)""

Comment: PS: I love batch so much, I've spent the last year nose diving into PowerShell hoping to never write another line of it again!

Comment: hm... with ""$($Env:!%~1!)"" error is: The string has no terminator: "
what the hell... 
i think i have to define it outside of the call. its very dirty and not very useful, but all sultions go wrong yet. :(

Comment: @Datasmuggler, added a new section of code that I was able to get to work.

Comment: yes, i think this will be the only solution.
at the end the packs.txt will have many urls and other variables.
so i will read all at the beginning and pass them to the variable inside the powershell command.